# H2O MOJO (Model ObJect, Optimized): Associating [columns] with [domains]

Tags: r, h2o

I am using R v3.3.2 and H2O V3.10.2.1 on a Linux server.

I saved a model to MOJO via `h2o.download_mojo`. This resulting file is a .zip file.  In the .zip file are these text files:

```
model.ini
domains/d000.txt
domains/d001.txt
domains/d002.txt
domains/d003.txt
domains/d004.txt
domains/d005.txt
domains/d006.txt
domains/d007.txt
domains/d008.txt
```

In the `model.ini` file there is a section `[columns]` that list the columns used to train my model:

```
[columns]
name
address01
address02
city
state
zip
phone number
age
```

In the `model.ini` file there is another section `[domains]` that lists filenames containing the data used during training for the categorical columns retained in the final model:

```
[domains]
1: 71 d000.txt
2: 71 d001.txt
3: 51 d002.txt
4: 3243 d003.txt
5: 3228 d004.txt
6: 2954 d005.txt
7: 2456 d006.txt
9: 616 d007.txt
```

How do I associated the column names listed in `[columns]` with their domain files listed in `[domains]`?

For example, the first domain file `d000.txt` does **not** contain data for the first column listed `name`.  In fact, `d000.txt` **does** contain data for column 3, `address02`.

How can I know this mapping:

```
1: 71 d000.txt    -->  address02
2: 71 d001.txt    -->  phone number
3: 51 d002.txt    -->  column 23
4: 3243 d003.txt  -->  column 58
```

A downloaded POJO (plain old java object) contained enough information to make this association.  I don't see a way to do this with a downloaded MOJO.

Something like a fourth column in the `[domains]` section would be helpful:

```
[domains]
1: 71 d000.txt "address02"
2: 71 d001.txt "phone number"
3: 51 d002.txt "column 23"
4: 3243 d003.txt "column 58"
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [domains] have a 0-based index for the column they belong to. In the example below, "7:" refers to the CAPSULE column: it has a 2-factor domain listed in the d000.txt file.

```
[columns]
AGE
RACE
DPROS
DCAPS
PSA
VOL
GLEASON
CAPSULE

[domains]
7: 2 d000.txt
```

Comment: Thanks!  My mistake was not realizing the numbering was 0-based.